# What rule governs the vowel alternations in Latin caput/capit-/-cep(t)-/-cipit-/-ciput?

Tags: phonology, indo-european, vowels, latin, optimality-theory

In different forms, the Latin root *caput* "head" appears with different vowels:

- **a-u**: *[caput](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/caput#Latin)* (nominative singular);
- **a-i**: *[capitis](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/caput#Latin)* (genitive singular), *capitī* (dative singular), *capita* (nominative plural), and so on;
- **i-i**: *[praecipitem](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/praeceps)* (accusative singular) "headlong", and so on; *[praecipitō](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/praecipito#Latin)* "I throw headlong"
- **e-0**: *[praeceps](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/praeceps)* (nominative singular) "headlong" (coming from *-cept-s*, as we may assume);
- **i-u**: *[oc-ciput](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/caput#Compos.C3.A9s)*, *sin-ciput*.

Are these alternations an expression of a general rule of Latin grammar?

Do they reflect some Proto-Indo-European alternation rule?

And from the point of view of universal grammar (linguistic theories with more predictive sterngth/explanatory force, such as optimality theory), can these alternations be explained as a consequence of certain universal (cross-linguistically valid) phonological constraints? (In which other languages are these constraints active too?)

Comment: Short /u/ - /i/ is a common alternation in Latin. Not sure about the others.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: Hmm where exactly? In theme vowels? Are you suggesting *u/i* are theme vowels in *caput/capit-*?

Comment: @Cerberus As for u/i alternation, I read about [sonus medius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_phonology#Sonus_medius): An intermediate vowel sound (likely [ɨ] or possibly its rounded counterpart [ʉ]) can be reconstructed for the classical period. Such a vowel is found in docvmentvm, optimvs, lacrima (also spelled docimentvm, optvmvs, lacrvma) and other words. It developed out of a historical short /u/ which was later fronted due to vowel reduction. In the vicinity of labial consonants, this sound was not as fronted and may have retained some rounding.(Allen 2004, p.56,59)

Comment: @Cerberus But in our case of *caput/capit-*, such an explanation wouldn't explain the clear distribution of the vowels between different forms: a labial consonant is near in all the forms. (Of course, further explanation can be thought of in terms of reduction affecting the different forms differently because of different syllabic (prosodic) structure of the forms. But this is not stated in the quoted excerpt.)

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev: Oh, yes, of course, *that* sound, as in *maxumus*. I actually didn't know this reduction also occurred in the endings *-us, -um*, although it makes sense, considering also how *-um* may be elided. I don't know how it worked exactly, but if Germanic also has *i/u* Wechsel...

Answer (score 11):

None of these can be explained by synchronic rules of Latin grammar, at least not in the classical age. Nor does this seem to be regular Proto-Indo-European ablaut, where one would expect something like **cp-/cep-/cop-*. Somehow many different allomorphs of *caput* exist; but allomorphs of other stems are plentiful in Latin and in most other languages. Many combinations of these allomorphs appear to be possible:

- **cap-/cep-/cip-** (semantic root)
- **-ut-/-it-** (suffix)

As to the **nominative singular *-ut* v. stem *-it-***, nominatives singular are normally different from the other forms of words or suffixes of the 3rd declension. *Homo, hominis; rex, regis; munus, muneris;* etc. Each nominative can probably be explained, and there are patterns, but I don't know about the *-u-* in *caput* specifically. And *-ud/-ut* is probably a Proto-Indo-European suffix, probably with its own rules. I have consulted *Walde-Hoffmann* (1938) and *Ernout-Meillet* (1959), but I couldn't find a real explanation for *-ut-* v. *-it-* in *caput, capitis*.

Interestingly, the same *-u/i-* allomorphs seem to exist in a Germanic word that is probably cognate to *caput* (so says [Philippa (2004–2009)](http://gtb.inl.nl/iWNTLINKS/DATADIR/paginazy.html?EWN%20/iWDB/search?actie=article_content&wdb=EWN&id=ewn005911), although the *Oxford English Dictionary* (2nd ed.) is sceptical). Dutch *hoofd* and German *Haupt* come from Proto-Germanic **haub-id-*, whereas Old English *heafod*, modern *head*, and Old Norse *haufuþ* come from **haub-ud-*. According to the *Oxford English Dictionary*, this *-id/ud-* constitutes "suffix ablaut". One would expect the Germanic and Latin suffixes to be cognates too, but, alas, etymological dictionaries rarely explain all the affixes, and I couldn't find it. Note that there is also a Germanic allomorph **hab-* leading to Proto-Germanic **hab-ud-*, Old English *hafud*, and Old Norse *höfuþ*.

As to the ***-cip-* in *praecipito***, an *-a-* in the first syllable of a verb normally changed into *-i-* after a prefix, in a certain phase of Latin. The same applies to *-ae-* and *-e-*, but not to *-o-* and *-u-*, as far as I know. The length of the vowel was generally preserved, so that long *-ā-* and *-ae-* become long *-ī-*, but short *-ă-* becomes short *-ĭ-*. Note that vowels did not (always) change in words formed in later phases of Latin. Nor did they change in the perfect stems of verbs. Hence:

> Maneo - remaneo - immanens
>
> Paro - reparo - apparans
>
> *(Present)* capio - recipio - incipiens
>
> *(Perfect)* cepi - recepi - receptus
>
> *(Present)* ago - redigo - redigiens
>
> *(Perfect)* egi - redegi - redactus

This may explain *-cip-* after many suffixes. However, it is possible that it is simply an older, unexplained allomorph.

As to ***-e-* in *praeceps***, this appears to be an allomorph that already existed in prehistoric Latin or earlier. (*Cep-* in the perfect is probably a lengthening of the vowel and explained through other mechanisms, but this is not certain.) The dictionaries above have no real explanation. It is possible that the *-e-* is due to contamination from words like *princeps* and *auceps*, which probably came from the *e* grade of the root of *capio*.  According to *Ernout-Meillet*, the root of *capio* had three allomorphs that seem to display regular Proto-Indo-European ablaut: **kēp-, *kōp-,* and **kəp-* (from which *cap-*). Notice that the stem of *princeps* etc. is *-cip-*, whereas that of *praeceps* etc. is *-cipit-.*

The *-e-* is only in the nominative singular, and it is not surprising in general that the nominative singular should be irregular. *Pontifex* (gen. *pontificis*) and *maleficus* come to mind, from *facio*, "make". Somehow both *-e-* and *-i-* occur. Compare also *pars, partis* leading to *expers, expertis*: the same nominative *-e-*, but no *-i-* in the stem.

As to the **disappearance of the suffix** in *anceps*, it is possible that it was syncopated, but it is more likely that the suffix was simply not used in all words derived from what may have been Proto-Indo-European **kh₂p*-/**kap-* (the origin of Proto-Indo-European **kap-ut* is not quite certain: **kh₂p*-/**kap-* may have come from a pre-Proto-Indo-European substrate language). This root meant something like "head", and later reflexes include some forms with the suffix *-ut/-ud*, others with *-elo-* (Greek *kephalê*), and probably others again with no suffix at all.

Note also that this root may be related to *capio, habeo,* and English/Germanic *have*/etc. (so suggests Walde), which come from a Proto-Indo-European root **kap-* (from **kh₂p-*/**kəp-*), or **gʰabʰ-* (from **gʰh₂bʰ-*) / **gʰebʰ-*, but this is uncertain. (These Proto-Indo-European roots may be variants on and reflexes of a pre-Proto-Indo-European substrate root, so suggests Philippa, *Etymologisch Woordenboek van het Nederlands* (2004–2009), ['hebben'](http://gtb.inl.nl/iWNTLINKS/DATADIR/paginazy.html?EWN%20/iWDB/search?actie=article_content&wdb=EWN&id=ewn005673)).

Words derived from the *capio* root exist that mean something like "recepticle, container" (notice *cep*-), and a semantic shift from pottery to head is a common phenomenon. Cf. Latin *testa* "(piece of) earthen pot", from *torreo* "burn" (related *toast*), which lead to French *tête* "head" and similar words in other Romance languages. Cf. also Latin *cuppa* "cup", probably from a non-Proto-Indo-European language ([Philippa](http://gtb.inl.nl/iWNTLINKS/DATADIR/paginazy.html?EWN%20/iWDB/search?actie=article_content&wdb=EWN&id=ewn007179)), which probably led to English *cup*, Dutch *kop* "cup; head (informal)", German *Kopf* "head (informal)". The original Proto-Indo-European root for "head" was [**ker-*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/19926/3036), "head, horn", from which *horn, cerebrum, cervix, unicorn, triceratops*; somehow the central word for "head" was replaced often in the successor languages.

Comment: Andrew Sihler (Sihler 1995) argues that in Proto-Italic short vowels e, i, o, u "merged nearly completely" into e (in the medial position), which turned later into i before a single consonant: GEN.SG. *kaputes->capitis.

Comment: @AlexB.: Right, that makes sense. So then was the u in caput long, and in the oblique forms short? Because it is now short in caput. Now all we need to know is how PI vowel lengths worked...

Comment: @Cerberus The merger brought to our attention by @alex-b is said to occur "in the medial position". The examples from the Q with *u* are all with *u* in the last syllable (*caput*, *occiput*). I'd understand "medial" as not in the last syllable, and then this matches the data: here, in the last syllables, the old `*u` didn't undergo this merger. But my understanding of "medial" may be wrong. As for vowel lengths in different forms, of course, that's an interesting direction to look into, because IE languages show some primary or secondary ablaut differences between NomSg and other forms.

Comment: @Cerberus As for IE languages showing some ablaut differences between NomSg and other forms, a quick link I can give is to the Wikipedia example with declension of "father" in Greek: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_ablaut#Ablaut_grades Their other related, more complex (suffixed) example is with the reconstructed proto-IE word ` *pértus` (assumed to give Eng. "fort", Latin "port"): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_ablaut#Grammatical_function , which I don't like because it doesn't refer immediately to any real data from real languages and has no references.